# Can I publish an agent version and manage environments on Dialogflow V2 API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

Can I publish an agent version on an environment using the Dialogflow V2 API?
I can't find any documentation on how to do that.
The doc about versions and environments only mentions doing this using the console (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-versions).
And the API doc of the agent environments resource only contains a *list* method (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.environments).
Does it mean that every change done using the API is automatically reflected in production?
Or does it mean that every change done by API is staged, and can only go to production by manually accessing the console and publishing the new version?
Both options seems terrible by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not possible to manage agent versions through the Dialogflow API, it seems that this feature is already being contemplated to be integrated to Dialogflow; however, there is no an ETA for its implementation. You can follow up this request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/153750593).